# +, ', " disappears in php GET search form

Tags: php, forms, input, sanitization

I have a search form. I use the following line to get the value. When it returns, it replaces plus sign to space, letters after single/double quotes are deleted. I want to enable users to search for the keywords they want. How can I allow these letters to display?

```
$title = trim(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'title', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS));
```

When I send with GET.

```
header("Location:http://site.org/search/?title=$title");
```

I tried using urlencode() and works for plus signs, but it didn't work for quotes. For example c"s would return c"s.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to change the quotes? If you send it in a url, `urlencode` will encode only the characters that need to be encoded.

Comment: I want to make it search for books title records which may contain a single quote or apostrophe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are special characters that correspond to what they are appearing to be, for instance a plus in a *GET* request corresponds to a space.

Please see [this link](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php).

You will have to replace these characters before you redirect. You can do this with `urlencode`.

Comment: I see. I tried `header("Location:http://site.org/search/?title=".urlencode($title).");` It works for plus signs. Single quote displays in the <input>. Double quote strips the rest of letters and I can't get single quote to match with the search result. The url gets encoded for + to %2B, but single quotes stays as '.

Comment: When I run `urlencode('"')`, I get `%22` as output, and `urlencode("'")` outputs `%27`

Comment: I get that output, too, when I echo it, but it doesn't show up on the url above. Single quote displays `...org/?title='` For plus sign, it shows %2B.

Comment: If I run this: `header("Location:index.php?a=".urlencode("'"));`, it takes me to my index page with the proper variable: `index.php?a=%27`.

Answer (score 0):

From the manual for FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS

> HTML-escape '"<>& and characters with ASCII value less than 32,
>   optionally strip or encode other special characters.

If the ascii value of the characters you are trying to are below 32, you will probably need to go a different route.

Comment: Right, it makes sense. Quotes are being stripped.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode / escape your data for the medium you are outputting to:

- use `url_encode` to send the variables via a url;
- use prepared statements with bound variables to query the database, that way you are safe from sql injection and you can search for texts with quotes in the database;
- use `htmlspecialchars` to output your results to html or something like `json_encode` to send it to javascript.